# javascript "or" statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors

I use the following to fire a js function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gl a').do_this({
```

So any link within div class .gl activates function do_this.. simple

Now, i also want to fire the same function on another div link too, can I do something like:

```
( $('.gl a') OR $('.gm a') ).do_this({
```

Tried all combinations but not working as yet, or do i simply have to duplicate the whole thing for the other class?

Comment: You want it to affect one *or* the other, but *not* both?

Comment: Thanks for the -1... Care to explain why? Really boosts ones desire to learn and try!

Comment: Um, since I was notified of that comment, I'll respond: the down-vote wasn't from me, but you asked a vague question with no clarification of your intent when asked. You also accepted an answer which doesn't seem to meet what little criteria you specified in your question ('OR', the accepted answer is definitely an 'AND'). I can't say why you were down-voted, but I'd suggest maybe trying to research a little more before asking in future. Don't stop asking, or learning, just try and demonstrate some research and explain what you tried and what failed for you.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, the question re the -1 was not directed at you. It was at whoever did it. They really should make users explain them i think. As I said in the comment for the answer I accepted, it is indeed an either, or both, or as you say 'and'. I did try many things. Will clarify more in future. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) like so:

```
$('.gl a, .gm a');
```

This will work if either one is present, or if both are present; I'm assuming this is what you want.

Comment: That's not, strictly speaking, an 'or' (but I'm unsure as to what the OP wants).

Comment: This will work if either or both are present, unless the OP wants an exclusive or.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: right. I'm also uncertain what OP actually wants here. If he really means it like `a` OR `b` this would not satisfy the requirement

Comment: @jAndy ambiguities of the English language :) Yes, I agree this doesn't translate to a boolean `OR`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Thank you. Perfect, and so damn simple! A css multiple translated over to js, although probably the other way around. Thanks again. Yes, it's a literal 'or' not one or the other, so a both - English language anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a ternary to identify a specific group to affect, if you genuinely mean an exclusive OR:

```
var groupToAffect = $('.gl a').length ? $('.gl a') : $('.gm a');
groupToAffect.do_this();
```

This tests that the selector `$('.gl a')` returns a non-empty collection of elements and, if it does, stores the elements returned by that selector in the `groupToAffect` variable. If it returns zero (falsey) elements, then it instead assigns the elements returned by the selector `$('.gm a')` to that variable; which is then used with the `do_this()` method/plugin.

Comment: I think you mean `$('.gl a').length ? $('.gl a') : $('.gm a');`

Comment: @Nimphious, indeed I did! Why hello again, English language; it's been quite some time... =/

Comment: Oh, to avoid a second lookup, you should be able to do it like this, too: `var gl = $('.gl a'), group = gl.length ? gl : $(.gm a');` Could be useful if it's used a lot and performance is important.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery object arrays can be grouped together with a concat. Then iterate over all the objects.

```
$( [].concat($('.gl a'),$('.gm a')) ).each(function(index){
    this.do_this({ //...
});
```